# Busy signal always using the external speaker after upgrading to IOS 10

Tags: speakers, iphone, ios

I have an iPhone 6s.

Since upgrading to IOS 10 (version 10.0.1), whenever I make a phone call and the destination number is busy, the busy signal comes from the external speaker (on the lower right border) instead of the phone speaker (in the middle above the screen); it's just like having speakerphone enabled, but it isn't, and this only happens for the busy signal: if the number is not busy, all audio correctly comes from the phone speaker (unless, of course, I actually enable speakerphone).

Is this a bug? Has this been noticed by anyone else? Can it be fixed?

---

### Update:

I opened a support call with Apple, which said no one has yet reported this issue, and then suggested first a hard reboot of the phone, then to reset all settings; I tried both, and I also updated IOS to version 10.0.2.

The issue still remains.

Comment: I can confirm it's not just you. I am also having this issue. 6+ on iOS 10.0.2

Comment: Yeah, same issue here. iPhone 6S 10.1.1

Comment: Same issue here on 6S with 10.2..